# An exception occurred during task execution.The error was: TypeError: write() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not list

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
---
# file: access_token/tasks

- name: Verify if tenantname is provided
  fail: msg="Please provide the name of the tenant."
  when: tenantname is undefined

- name: Verify if tenantsecret is provided
  fail: msg="Please provide the application secret of the tenant."
  when: tenantsecret is undefined

- name: Send OAuth details
  shell: |
    curl -X POST \
    '{{mlp_uaa}}' \
    -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -d 'client_id={{tenantname}}&client_secret={{tenantsecret}}'
  register: token_details

- debug:
#   var=token_details.stdout_lines
    var: (token_details.stdout | from_json).access_token

# uri module, which fails
- name: Send OAuth details2
  uri:
    url: "{{mlp_uaa}}"
    method: POST
    body:
      - client_id: "{{tenantname}}"
      - client_secret: "{{tenantsecret}}"
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      body_format: json
      Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    return_content: yes
  register: token_details2
```

Could you please tell me why using shell I am able to to get the value of the `access_token` and using URI I am getting the output (Note that I am using `Ubuntu 16.04`) : [image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `body_format: json`, so you must pass a JSON string as the body:

> If body_format is set to 'json' it will take an already formatted JSON string or convert a data structure into JSON.

Currently you are passing a two-element list object:

```
- client_id: "{{tenantname}}"
- client_secret: "{{tenantsecret}}"
```

JSON string with the same list looks like this:

```
'{ [ "client_id": "{{tenantname}}", "client_secret":  "{{tenantsecret}}" ] }'
```